# Need to get productdata and categorydata from wordpress data base

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress installation which i installed codeigniter in. This all goes good and i also got access to the database. Now i have a plugin installed for wordpress called: Woocommerce. With this plugin you can store products and productdata in your database. Now i need to access the data from my woocommerce products within the codeigniter application.

Woocommerce stores its products like this:

All products goes into a table called: wp_posts In this table there is a column defined called: post_type Woocommerce identifies the posts as products when post_type is set to product .

Now there is another table called wp_postmeta. In this table all of the productdata get stored into 4 columns: 1. meta_id [identifier for the metarow] 2. post_id [identifies itself to the wp_posts table] 3. meta_key [there will go several keys into it like: sale_price, stock, additional_price etc..] 4. meta_value [for each key there is a value.]

Now i required to get listing of all category and product ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to while product:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../public_html/wp-blog-header.php');

global $post, $product;
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=product');
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```